# Yield Method confusion

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a confusion. I read somewhere that `Thread.yield()` method causes the currently running thread to pause and give chance to remaining thread of "Same Priority".

Now always it is same priority threads executed or higher priority threads can also be executed. And if suppose currently running thread has some lock on some object, after executing yeild method will it give its lock?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `Thread.yield()` the current thread pauses and allows the scheduler to run a different thread. Priorities are managed by the scheduler.

And no, of course not - you don't release any locks. Doing so would break synchronization.

Comment: Ok I got your point. But I am thinking that when current thread pauses and some other thread is given a chance to execute then what will be  the priority of that thread. Higher or same as the thread that was paused.

Comment: You have no idea nor can you predict it, that's the scheduler's job.

Comment: You shouldn't normally have to call yield

Comment: `Thread.yield` is THE definition of OS defined behavior. And using it can lead to some pretty.. interesting results. One would expect that yielding a thread would indicate to the scheduler that this thread doesn't have any important work to do, hence lowering its priority, right? Well some Solaris (I think?) does the exact opposite of that and increases the yielding threads priority..

Comment: I believe it's a hint, not an obligation